# Deodexing apk files

Tags: android, android-source, android-launcher

I'm trying to build the AOSP ICS launcher(Launcher2) from the AOSP source, and install it into any Android device, but I keep getting a INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT error upon adb install. I suspect it's because the apk is odexed, as there is a Launcher2.apk and a Launcher2.odex file in the out directory.

If this is the case, how do I deodex the apk?

Thanks!